# Acessing MongoDB on the Client-Side using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I know this is completely unsafe to do because the user would have control over the credentials. But in application I'm building I don't really care it's completely insecure.

Is there a way to open a connection on a MongoDb using client-side JavaScript ? 
The JavaScript driver on Mongo's website is for use on NodeJS only.

Thanks,

Fred_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the mongodb [http interfaces list](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface). Start a mongodb, start the sever, request/modify a data from that server using ajax.