# Can I connect to a Mongodb from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want connect to a mongoDb instance from javascript function and fetch the details.. Is it possible ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Acessing MongoDB on the Client-Side using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665371/acessing-mongodb-on-the-client-side-using-javascript)

Comment: I installed mongoser-src, but not able to connect..

Answer (score 0):

Use MongoDB native driver for Node.js: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native